# How to set a password on recovery mode in GRUB

Tags: grub2, password, password-recovery

Any one can reset the root and other user's password by going in recovery mode. SO I want that on the recovery option GRUB require a password to enter in recovery mode. But user can login UBUNTU without a password requirement.

Any idea?

I do't want to set GRUB2 password. I want to set password on recovery mode option or After recovery mode system need a password to go ahead.

Comment: That does not really help as you can bypass the by booting a live CD and doing the same thing (or other cracks). You need to restrict physical access. Physical access == root access

Comment: @bodhi.zazen yea ... but right now i need to set a password to prevent the password reset of root user.

Comment: Maybe the answer of http://askubuntu.com/questions/31605/how-to-secure-grub-recovery-mode can help you.

Comment: You are better off encrypting your install.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to secure grub recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/31605/how-to-secure-grub-recovery-mode)