# How to prevent the people from using 'e' to change the 'config' in grub?

Tags: boot, grub2, password, customization, privacy

I'm really stumped this time because, I've tried to configure the `10_linux` & the `00_header` the `/boot/grub/grub.conf`

I've tried it many times, but unable to protect it with *`Password`*

Please do help to get the **Grub** protected by means of **Password**?

Comment: You can reduce the seconds of the boot i.e make it a second by doing so you can prevent it @RandolAlbert

Comment: It's already at zero what I'm trying to do is password protect it. @Sridrah

Comment: Visit this http://www.howtogeek.com/102009/how-to-password-protect-ubuntus-boot-loader/ and also this https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to secure grub recovery mode](http://askubuntu.com/questions/31605/how-to-secure-grub-recovery-mode). And must reads: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2/Passwords and section  9 of https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/legacy/grub.html. **Test** these well in a virtual system **before** using it in your mail system. Any mistake can cause undesirable effects.

Comment: thank you and I will try this again but I don't know if it will work. @Ron

Comment: If I'm right you have made 2 mistae. 1: config file name is *grub.cfg*. 2: edit config file @ /etc/grub/grub.cfg

Comment: There is nothing in that file either @totti

Comment: Possibly bug in current version. Upgrade/downgrade to another version.

Comment: How would I upgrade that file @totti

Comment: Search for grub in software center. Downgrading need super user knowledge.